# How to keep partial templates in separate page and switch according to child page

Tags: ember.js

In my app, I have a `home` page. this home page has 2 child as `service` and `contact`. now the home page have common header. ( it requires other child pages too ) and when child page loads i require to load the partial header template to their own.

And also, I require to maintain the child page headers in separate hbs too.
How to achieve this?

here is my try :

```
<header>
    <h2>Home page header </h2>
  <p class="service">Partial content for Service to be maintained in separate hbs file </p>
    <p class="contact">Partial content for contact to be maintained in separate page </p>
</header>

{{outlet}}
```

[Twiddle here](https://ember-twiddle.com/9a926b7ecd5a7953e53c98d1201996f4?openFiles=templates.home.hbs%2C&route=%2Fhome%2Fservice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named outlets](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/named-outlets-and-pods/7807) like this:

**service.js route**

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    // Render default outlet   
    this.render();
    // render extra outlets
    this.render("service-header", {
        outlet: "header",
        into: "home"
    });
}
```

**service.js controller**

```
mypasseddata: 'my passed service data'
```

**home.hbs**

```
<header>
    <h2>Home page header </h2>
  {{outlet 'header'}}
</header>

{{outlet}}
```

**service-header.hbs template**

```
{{yield}}
    <p class="service">Partial content for Service to be maintained in separate hbs file </p>
{{mypasseddata}}
```

Please, take a look at this [modified twiddle of yours](https://ember-twiddle.com/1309194ef6fdabc83315d3c5c193fc57).

Comment: Is there is no in-build approach use like `outlet`?

Comment: How to pass some data to home page from `service` or `contanct` to show in header?

Comment: Yes you can use outlets and pass data from controllers to these outlets. I've updated the twiddle, I will update the answer in a while.